# The algebras and coalgebras of the homology functor

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory

My question is very simple, but I suspect far from the intuition with which singular homology is introduced.

Consider singular homology as a functor
$$H_n : {\sf Top}\times{\sf Ab} \to \sf Ab$$
This means that for every topological space $X$, $H_n(X,-)$ is an endofunctor of the category of abelian groups.

I am trying to work out what is an algebra for the endofunctor $H_*(X,-):A\mapsto \bigoplus_n H_n(X,A)$, i.e. a map $\alpha : H_*(X,A)\to A$, seen as object of a category where morphisms are abelian group homomorphisms such that $f ∘ α_n = β_n ∘ Hₙ(X,f)$, when $(A,\alpha),(B,\beta)$ are as above, and each of them splits, by the universal property of coproducts, as a family $\alpha_n : H_n(X,A)\to A$, $\beta_n : H_n(X,B)\to B$.

To put it simply, I'm doing this strange thing to let a fixed *space* act on an Abelian group, letting the coefficients run free over all $\sf Ab$.

> Is this a thing?

If yes, do you know how should I picture $H_*(X)$-algebras? With a little bit of work, using universal coefficients, one can see that such an algebra is just a coset of a cohomology class $[α']$ in $H^n(X,A)$, considered up-to an element of a certain $Ext^1$, call it $α''$, that can be regarded as an extension $0 → A → E → H_{n-1}(X,A) → 0$. In particular, when $A$ is divisible, $\alpha''$ will be zero and an algebra is just a cohomology class.

What could possibly be an interpretation for such a correspondence? Is it a better idea to study *co*algebras ([link](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coalgebra+for+an+endofunctor)), considered as dual maps $\alpha : A \to \prod_n H_n(X,A)$? (Meaning: do they have a better interpretation, are they a more natural object associated to $H_*(X,-)$, despite the fact that there is no similar way to use UCT to "represent" them? I would say yes, handwaving with the fact that $X$ is -obviously- a comonoid in $\sf Top$ and that Künneth theorem makes $H_*(X,A)$ a comonoid.)